# Why does my background image only sometimes show?

Tags: caching, theming

I have a background image set for #region-header-first on this page http://www.smith-howard.com/resources?type=article&sort_bef_combine=created%2BDESC

However, it only shows sometimes in Chrome (mostly not). If I clear all Drupal caches (and browser cache) it will show once, but on the first refresh and so on it doesn't show any more.

If i check web inspector in safari (where it always works), it definitely shows the background image in the CSS.

```
#region-header-first background:url(http://www.smith-howard.com/sites/default/files/resources-articles2_0.jpg);
```

But inspecting it in Chrome doesn't show that the background image is set in the CSS at all. This is just mind boggling.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The picture with the two women always show for me with Chrome, Firefox and Explorer. Perhaps you have a Chrome add-on that is blocking it?

Comment: In chrome? Firefox and Safari work fine for me, it's Chrome that's the issue.

Comment: yup I'm on Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 m

Comment: are you using any chrome extensions/addons?

Comment: Try **CTRL + SHIFT + N** to browse in incognito.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in Incognito.Chrome is the only browser I ever use to log into the Drupal admin with, and ironically it's the browser it's not working in. I test logged out/in, cleared cache and everything but it keeps doing the same thing.

Comment: There is something happening to your Chrome only, it's just you. Try going to your page in incognito.

Comment: Works fine in incognito. My co-worker who edits the site as well has the same issue on a PC with his Firefox browser.

Comment: Go back to regular mode and for url put `chrome://extensions/` do you have any extensions enabled?

Comment: I disabled any extensions I had and cleared cache again. Also, the issue happens while logged in or not.

Comment: Now it's only not showing when I'm logged in as admin. It's showing if I'm logged out. Wasn't doing this the other day.

Comment: umm humm... install [web developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) extension and edit the css. See if you can CTRL + F and find the background image. or look for the div `#region-header-first`

Comment: I had done that. The image (url) doesn't even show in the CSS inspection. However in my other browsers it does and when not logged in as admin in chrome it shows too.

Comment: Beginning to think I just need to chalk it up to another one of Drupal's many anomalies. As long as visitors can see it I guess it's fine.

Comment: after looking at your css, it shows the your bg code as embeded styles. How did you add this css? Did you add it to a .css file or did you use the html <style> //css goes here </style> way?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, another developer created this site.

Comment: ok, it appears to me that the code was embedded using <style> //css goes here </style> rather than adding it to your theme's .css file. So it appears that the block/view or whatever was used to add the <style> //css goes here </style> is only visible to anonymous users.

Comment: Ahhhh I do see that now that I'm logged out. That just seems ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, if you want, you can check all your blocks and views and template files to see if you can find the HTML (as you can see it when you view source)

```
    <style type="text/css" media="all"> 
    .not-front #region-header-first .field-name-field-headline,.not-front #region-header-first .field-name-field-subhead{color:#ffffff !important;}
    </style>
```

code and remove it, OR don't worry about it and just add

```
.not-front #region-header-first .field-name-field-headline,.not-front #region-header-first .field-name-field-subhead{color:#ffffff !important;}
```

to your theme's .css file

Comment: There are about a million views and blocks in this build (and for such a simple site too) I think I'll just leave it as is. I really appreciate the help.